# Gradle related error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently started using the android studio. Just after installing and downloading all the requisite files, I am welcomed by this error,"Failed to find the target with the hash string 'API 27'....", whereas I already have both **API 27 and 28** installed (although 28 shows up to be partly installed).

I am completely new to this software.

[Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhHIr.png)

[image]

[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjNf.png)

[image]

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylDUg.png)

[image: 1]]

Comment: change compileSdkVersion "API 27" to compileSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 1):

you should use like below in gradle

```
{

        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }

}
```

don't write like `compileSdkVersion 'API 27'` its `compileSdkVersion 27` only